# How to copy numpy array values at certain indices

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array and I want to copy parts of the array at certain indices to a different array.

```
arr = np.arange(10)
np.random.shuffle(arr)
print arr
[0 3 4 2 5 6 8 7 9 1]
```

I want to copy the value at the indices

```
copy_indices = [3, 7, 8]
```

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: `newarr = arr[copy_indices]`.

Comment: You're right @Evert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this approach?

```
In [16]: arr
Out[16]: array([2, 9, 5, 6, 1, 4, 7, 8, 3, 0])

In [17]: copy_indices
Out[17]: [3, 7, 8]

In [18]: sliced_arr = np.copy(arr[copy_indices, ])

# alternatively
# In [18]: sliced_arr = arr[copy_indices, ]

In [19]: sliced_arr
Out[19]: array([6, 8, 3])
```

---

**P.S.:** Advanced indexing (as here) actually returns [*copy* of the array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). So, the use of `np.copy()` is optional.